# Cakephp custom config file

Tags: cakephp, configuration, customization

Basically I want to create file in Config folder, for example `app/Config/emailProvider.php` where I can save name of the class to instantiate.(Something similar to database.php)

The problem is I don't know how to load file, I've tried with

```
Configure::config('email', new PhpReader());
Configure::load('emailProvider', 'default')
```

but I always get an error `CORE/Cake/Core/Configure.php line 298 → PhpReader->read(string)`

Comment: That line doesn't help much, what is the *exact* error message?

Comment: but cakephp have his own librarie for emails why you don't use this?

Comment: Because I can't get it to work with mandrill.

Comment: In the bootstrap.php, wouldn't you just use `require_once 'emailProvider.php';`?

Comment: could you please mention the version of cakephp you are working with?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, let's assume that your config file app/Config/emailProvider.php contains the following contents:

```
<?php
$config['MyTestApp']['email'] = 'bob@gmail.com';
.....
```

Next thing is that you need to tell your app to load the custom config file by including it in bootstrap.php inside app/Config:

```
Configure::load('emailProvider');
```

Then, you can access it from your controller as below:

```
$email = Configure::read('MyTestApp.email');
```

[Reference link](https://davebaker.me/2013/07/16/custom-configure-files-in-cakephp/)